# Displaying blob file (png, jpg, pdf, jpeg) on a new window or a modal in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, blob

I'm new to PHP development and a greenhorn in Yii2. I have uploaded a file to the database using blob and can retrieve/view the data only by downloading. But my question is, how do I display/view the blob file without downloading the file, as in either displaying it on a new tab/window or a modal popup?

Some idea I have is creating a temporary file in the server and calling/echo-ing the temp file path. And to achieve that I would need to implement `tmpfile()` or/and `tempnam()` functions.  But from the little research I did, I cant seem to find a decent example on how to achieve this.

Any ideas or insight on how to accomplish this?

I provide what I have now to make it clear on what step I am currently.

**controller to view file blob**

```
        public function actionGetDbDocument($docId) {
        $model = MasterIncomings::findOne($docId);
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-length: ' . $model->file_size);
        header('Content-Type: ' . $model->file_type);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $model->filename);
        echo $model->file_blob;
```

**view to call the function above to display the blob file**

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'index_no',
            'label' => "Index Number",
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($model) {
                $title = "Uploaded By: " . $model->uploader_fullname . "\n" . "At time: " . MyFormatter::asDateTime_Read($model->created_at);
                $title .= "\nRemarks: " . $model->remarks;
                return Html::a($model->index_no . ' <i class="fas fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>', "view?id=$model->id", ["title" => $title])
                        . Html::a("<i class='far fa-file-alt fa-lg' ></i>", ['/working/mi/get-db-document', 'docId' => $model->id] ,
                        ['target' => "_blank", 'class' => 'm-2', 'title' => "Click to view me"]);
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Try removing the line that sets Content-Disposition header or change it to `inline` instead of `attachment`. `Content-Disposition: attachment` is what tells browser to offer download instead of displaying it directly. You also need to make sure that there is proper mime type set in `Content-Type` header.

Comment: This works, thanks @MichalHynčica! May i know what to read on to know more about those header contents as what is pragma and stuff? I took the block of code straight from Yii website. For the validation when saving, i set the checkMimeTypeExtension to false because if i didnt, the file seem to not be saving.

Comment: For example [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) has pretty good explanations of headers. The pragma header itself is a bit problematic because it's "implementation dependent" which means it can contain pretty much anything. It's often used to control cache for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Ah it took quite some time but that was a good read. Thanks a lot for the sharing @MichalHynčica. Highly appreciate it!